# Reading Json file in PowerBI in separate columns

Tags: json, powerbi

I am having the following json string

```
"custom":{
  "dimensions":[
    {"UserName":"TestName"},
    {"Client":"303"},
    {"NumberOfRecords":"1000"},
    {"FirstAttempt":"Yes"},
    {"DeveloperMode":"true"}
  ]
}
```

I wanted to see this Json file in PowerBI in separate columns for each. I tried in google from last few days but no help with this format. Any can help me with Power query.

Answer (score 0):

So what did you try?

[image]

But Assuming you found the above datasource, it usually comes down to the specific json structure - some structures are easier to import than others...